# Enhancing Samba with a plugin?

Tags: samba

Is it possible to enhance Samba with a plugin? Specifically, I would like to serve my own content, not a 1-to-1 filesystem copy.

Thanks for you answers!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, see the vfs modules.

End-user docs on some existing ones shipped with samba: http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/Samba-HOWTO-Collection/VFS.html

Developer docs: http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/Samba-Developers-Guide/vfs.html

Here is another module that on-the-fly transcodes audio files: http://file-ext-map.sourceforge.net/